# how to order pop up in javascript?

Tags: javascript

the code is JavaScript code that create a pop up when the user set time in an input ( lets say 5 seconds) and then the pop up displays.

why do you need to turn **on** and **off** the event listener all the time 
and what it means to turn it on and off?

here is the code;

```
var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
var input = document.getElementById("popup-delay");
var showButton = document.getElementById("popup-show");
var closeButton = document.getElementById("popup-close");

showButton.addEventListener("click", function onShowClick () {
  // get the user input and convert it into a number
  var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
  // if the input is not a number
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    // warn the user
    alert("NaN (Not A Number) !");
  }
  // otherwise
  else {
    // convert milliseconds to seconds
    var delay = value * 1000;
    // turn off the click listener on the "Show" button**
    showButton.removeEventListener("click", onShowClick);
    // start the countdown to show the popup
    setTimeout(function () {
      // show the popup
      popup.style.display = "block";
      // turn on the click listener on the "Close" button**
      closeButton.addEventListener("click", function onCloseClick () {
        // turn off the click listener on the "Close" button**
        closeButton.removeEventListener("click", onCloseClick);
        // turn on the click listener on the "Show" button**
        showButton.addEventListener("click", onShowClick);
        // hide the popup
        popup.style.display = "none";
      });
    }, delay);
  }
});
```

Comment: My guess is that: Every time you click the button a popup window is queued. So if you didn't remove the `onclick` listener you could queue up more than one popup by repeatedly pressing the button.

Comment: I agree with @Olian04 - it seems its a way to prevent users to button mashing. But I would suggest disabling the buttons as soon as they are clicked. This way actually provides feedback to the user (hey don't click me again). Otherwise the user will think the button is broken if they keep clicking it and nothing happens.

Comment: In this particular example you wouldn't get duplicate popups since a single popup is being shown or hidden. However, what could happen is flickering: user clicks the show button twice, popup shows, they hide it, it shows a second time.

Comment: hoo ok useful comments.. thanks'

Comment: but when you turn off add listner event dosent it cancel the all thing???